# Cannot build NetCore 2.1 WebApp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

**Action:**
I create a new ASP.NET Web Application in NetCore Framework 2.1.

I do not add anything. I have a blank application. I click build the solution.

**Result:**

I get "rzc discover exited with code 1" error and the build fails.
I cannot even build a blank project created by the IDE.

I have tried everything I could find.

- repairing Visual Studio
- cleaning solution
- deleting bin folder
- running VS with administrative rights

The error points to the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.CodeGeneration.targets file line 69: this piece of code:

```
<RazorTagHelper 
    Debug="$(_RazorDebugTagHelperTask)"
    DebugTool="$(_RazorDebugTagHelperTool)"
    ToolAssembly="$(_RazorToolAssembly)"
    UseServer="$(UseRazorBuildServer)"
    ForceServer="$(_RazorForceBuildServer)"    
    SuppressCurrentUserOnlyPipeOptions="$(_RazorSuppressCurrentUserOnlyPipeOptions)"
    PipeName="$(_RazorBuildServerPipeName)"
    Version="$(RazorLangVersion)"
    Configuration="@(ResolvedRazorConfiguration)"
    Extensions="@(ResolvedRazorExtension)"
    Assemblies="@(RazorReferencePath)"
    ProjectRoot="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
    TagHelperManifest="$(_RazorTagHelperOutputCache)">
    <Output
        TaskParameter="TagHelperManifest"
        ItemName="FileWrites"/>
</RazorTagHelper>
```

Tools:

- Visual Studio Community 2017 15.8.5
- DotNet version 2.1.402

Please help.

Comment: What Visual Studio template did you use to create the blank solution? Or what `dotnet new` command was used? Keep in mind that you must make it possible for others to reproduce the issue.

Comment: simply File -> New Project -> .Net Core and ASP.NET Core Web Application -> click OK

Then .NET CORE and ASP.NET Core 2.1 selected -> Web Application selected -> click OK

But it doesn't matter if I add a new project to an existing solution (empty or not) or create a new solution with that project.

Comment: Unfortunately, cannot reproduce this issue on my machine. Try to use `dotnet new` to create an empty project and then use `dotnet build` to build it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/2554#issuecomment-416314860) on GitHub.

Based on what is explained in the issue, the problem might lay on the fact that your project is probably is mixing packages from stable (2.1) and previewed version of .Net Core.

It might be enough to update the references in your project to use the correct .NET core version package

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" Version="2.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores" Version="2.1.3" />
```

Comment: It may be better to quote the relevant parts of what you are linking to in case it cannot be reached in the future.

Comment: Just for the record, I read that before and nothing of what they say there works. :)
But thx for posting I should have mentioned in my post I read that.

As to the references you mentioned it was someone's app and he in fact messed up the references. 

In my case, I have a fresh new project build by the IDE. And it has only the basic reference.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved this error: "rzc discover exited with code 1.", by turning of "Real-time protection" in in Windows Security.
I exclude "dotnet.exe" from "Windows Defender Antivirus" scan and/or allow it through "Controlled folder access".

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it fixed. After trying all suggestions here and at locations across the web without success.

I decided to treat the error as a flag that an assembly to interpret the Razor directives in the file is missing.

So, I installed the package **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design** and recompiled.

It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This answer fixed the issue for me https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20857

Needed to install the latest .NET version

Answer (score 0):

error rzc discover exited with code -2147450730

Please you need sdk version according your project. Check the version in your project.  To solve this problem, please install required sdk version.